# Java version for Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: java, 14.10

What version of Java should I load onto my Ubuntu 14.10 O/S. Also if there is a specific process needed to install same please provide **explicit** instructions as I am first learning to use Linux?

Answer (score -1):

```
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre 

 sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

[Here More help for installing java in ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

Comment: Why do you think mike needs the Open JDK Development Toolkit? He asked for **explicit** instructions.

Comment: might he don't know much about how to install in java